# Launch screen is not working in iPad Device

Tags: ios, ipad, launch

in my project the Launch screen is not showing in Device(iPad Mini) but it showing in the simulator(iPad Retina,iPad Air,iPad 2), my deployment Target is 8.4 & my device also have 8.4 and i fixed the name LaunchImage.png(768*1024) & LaunchImage@2x.png(1536*2048) ,Device Orientation only for portrait & Device for ipad only help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You have to check iPad Version & if Your is iOS fix the Launch screen for iOS 6 or 7.

2.Check the Files are in correct .png Format or not.

Comment: i already fixed the launch image for ios 6 also not working,i checked that is correct png format only

Comment: one time i'm also getting the Same problem & i checked by copy the file & i put the project for launch image .xib in there the .png files getting some warning then i convert the  image in online  .png format  & it working.. try this

Comment: yes i save the jpeg file to png file in mac by get info now i convert it in online it working thanks